# Windows file API CloseHandle function throws an exception: "An invalid handle was specified"

Tags: winapi, exception, visual-c++

I've written function (in Visual C++ in MS VS 2013) not unlike as on

[Recursively searching for files in the computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639874/recursively-searching-for-files-in-the-computer?rq=1)

Below is my function's source code:

```
wstring FolderPathValidator::FindRequiredFolder(const wstring& p_InitialPath, wstring p_RequiredFolderName)
{
    wstring foundFolder = L"";
    wstring folderPath = p_InitialPath + L"\\*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW folderInfo;
    HANDLE search_handle = FindFirstFileW(folderPath.c_str(), &folderInfo);
    if (search_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        vector<wstring> folders;

        do
        {
            if (folderInfo.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if ((!lstrcmpW(folderInfo.cFileName, L".")) || (!lstrcmpW(folderInfo.cFileName, L"..")))
                    continue;
            }

            folderPath = p_InitialPath + L"\\" + wstring(folderInfo.cFileName);

            if (folderInfo.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if (folderInfo.cFileName == p_RequiredFolderName)
                {
                    foundFolder = folderInfo.cFileName;
                    return foundFolder;
                }
                folders.push_back(folderPath);
            }
        } while (FindNextFileW(search_handle, &folderInfo));

        CloseHandle(search_handle);

        for (vector<wstring>::iterator iter = folders.begin(), end = folders.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
            FindRequiredFolder(*iter, p_RequiredFolderName);
    }

    return foundFolder;
}
```

The funcion begins to work without problems. But when it try to execute the line

```
CloseHandle(search_handle);
```

then the following exception has place:

```
First step of exception handling on address 0x76D712C7 в WordsCounter.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.
```

Where 'WordsCounter' is the name of application executable file. The FindRequiredFolder function is the member of The FolderPathValidator class. FolderPathValidator class is located in static class library project. Both projects: the class library and C++ console application wich consumes the library are in the same solution. Among files and folders names sometimes occur Russian names in Cyrillic alphabet. But I don't think that Cyrillic folder or file names is the reason of this error. What the reason of this error? How can I correct it? Please help.

Comment: Offtopic: Instead of `if (folderInfo.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)` use `if ( (folderInfo.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0 )`. This will prevent compiler warning in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `FindClose` instead of `CloseHandle`. Where you read that you have to use CloseHandle?
2. Use T() or TEXT() macro, insteaf of L" prefix for unicode strings (`TEXT( "" )`).
3. Use `lstrcmp` without `W`. It is macro and calls lstrcmpW if your project is Unicode.

Comment: `2` and `3` are unrelated to the problem. Whether you explicitly use the Unicode APIs (with a `W` suffix) together with `L`-prefixed string literals, or the `_T`-macro with unspecified API versions (i.e. without an `A` or `W` suffix) is a matter of coding conventions, project goals, and personal taste. As long as you match API-calls and string literal encoding. The code is fine in this respect.

Comment: Ok, `2` and `3` were postscriptum. `1` is the answer of question.

Comment: Thanks FindClose helps!

Comment: I disagree with 2 and 3. However, 1 cannot be argued.