# How recursively find files with Unicode names in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, recursion, unicode

I found and modify solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639874/recursively-searching-for-files-in-the-computer):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//wofstream out;

void FindFile(const std::wstring &directory)
{
    std::wcout << endl << endl << endl << "FindFile(" << directory << ")" << std::endl;

    std::wstring tmp = directory + L"\\*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW file;
    HANDLE search_handle = FindFirstFileW(tmp.c_str(), &file);
    if (search_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::vector<std::wstring> directories;

        do
        {
            std::wcout << std::endl;
            std::wcout << "    [" << file.cFileName << "]" << std::endl;
            tmp = directory + L"\\" + std::wstring(file.cFileName);

            if (file.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if ((!lstrcmpW(file.cFileName, L".")) || (!lstrcmpW(file.cFileName, L".."))) {
                    std::wcout << "continuing..." << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                    std::wcout << "saving path to this directory" << std::endl;
                    directories.push_back(tmp);
                }
            } else {
                std::wcout << "save [" << tmp << "] as file" << std::endl;
            }

            //std::wcout << tmp << std::endl;
            //out << tmp << std::endl;
        }
        while (FindNextFileW(search_handle, &file));

        std::wcout << "all items inside current directory was worked out. close it's handle." << std::endl;
        FindClose(search_handle);

        for(std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iter = directories.begin(), end = directories.end(); iter != end; ++iter) {
            std::wcout << "recursively find in next directory: [" << *iter << "]" << std::endl;
            FindFile(*iter);
        }
    } else {
        std::wcout << "invalid handle value" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //out.open("C:\\temp\\found.txt");

    FindFile(L"C:\\test");

    //out.close();

    cout << "The end" << endl;
    string str;
    cin >> str;

    return 0;
}
```

but this code isn't working with folders or files with cyrillic names (but I use Unicode versions of all types and functions!)

**Update**: Application just finish, without any exceptions, as if all commands was executed.

**Update-2 (print-screen):** [image: print-screen]

Who had the same problem? Thanks for any help.

**SOLVED**
Thanks a lot to @zett42 !
After some refactoring working code looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

using namespace std;

vector<wstring> FindFiles(const std::wstring &directory) {
    vector<wstring> files;
    std::vector<std::wstring> directories;

    std::wstring fullPath = directory + L"\\*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW file;
    HANDLE search_handle = FindFirstFileW(fullPath.c_str(), &file);

    if (search_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return files;

    do
    {
        fullPath = directory + L"\\" + std::wstring(file.cFileName);

        if (!(file.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
            files.push_back(fullPath);
        else {
            if ((lstrcmpW(file.cFileName, L".")) && (lstrcmpW(file.cFileName, L"..")))
                directories.push_back(fullPath);
        }
    }
    while (FindNextFileW(search_handle, &file));

    FindClose(search_handle);

    for(std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iter = directories.begin(), end = directories.end(); iter != end; ++iter) {
        vector<wstring> newFiles = FindFiles(*iter);
        files.insert(files.begin(), newFiles.begin(), newFiles.end());
    }

    return files;
}

int main()
{
    _setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT );

    vector<wstring> files = FindFiles(L"E:\\test");

    wcout << L"All found files: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); ++i)
        wcout << files[i] << endl;

    cout << "The end" << endl;
    string str;
    cin >> str;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"... but this code doesn't working ..."_ can you explain this - does it skip them, do you see them with the wrong names, does the program crash?

Comment: no. application just finish, without any errors. (thanks, @RichardCritten )

Comment: Add some error checking for `FindFirstFileW` and `FindNextFileW` and if they are failing output the the result of `GetLastError`.  Also debug your program and single step it - in fact do the debugging 1st.

Comment: What insight have you gathered by running this under a debugger?

Comment: this code just don't print into console files, which contains Cyrillic characters. I add print-screen into my question body.

Comment: `std::wcout << "invalid handle value" << std::endl;` and other similar lines look wrong to me.

Comment: @RichardCritten: It probably does, but invokes the `const void*` template specialization. At any rate, those should be wide character string literals, e.g. `wcout << L"save [" << ...;`.

Comment: `std::wcout << "invalid handle value" << std::endl;` appears to work in VS2015+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, Unicode output to console doesn't work by default, even if you use `std::wcout`.

To make it work, insert the following line at the beginning of your program:

```
_setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT );
```

[`_setmode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx) and [`_fileno`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6wbdhx.aspx) are Microsoft specific function.

You may also have to change console font. I'm using Lucida Console which works fine for cyrillic letters.

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>      // _setmode()
#include <fcntl.h>   // _O_U16TEXT

int main()
{
    // Windows needs a little non-standard magic for Unicode console output.
    _setmode( _fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT );

    std::wcout << L"по русски\n";
}
```

Example should be saved as UTF-8 encoded file because of the Unicode string literal, but this is not relevant in your case because you don't have Unicode string literals.

I have successfully tested this code under MSVC2015 and MSVC2017 on Win10.

Comment: ok, thanks!) I will try to do it now and let you know about results :)
but, my aim is to get all paths inside "vector<wstring> files", not print them into console.

Comment: @V.Panchenko I don't see an issue with your code regarding that. I think it's just an output issue.

Comment: You want to "get" the paths?  What do you mean by "get"?  Do you want to put them into a vector?  Write them to a file?  Hunt them down in the woods?  What?

Comment: @Dan you can see OP is not native english speaker, but even I got that OP wants to `add` paths to a vector. That's what he is currently doing in code.

Comment: @DanKorn, put them into a vector)

Comment: @V.Panchenko I just noted that `std::cout` will crash when called after `_setmode()`. So you should change the `cout` in your main function to `wcout`.

Comment: @zett42, this solution works fine in my CLion 2017.1, but it doesn't work in Code Blocks 16.01 (compiler error: "_fileno was not declared in this scope"). How can I deal with it?

I use Code Blocks because I can't compile 32-bit application in CLion 2017.1 :(

Comment: @V.Panchenko I have no idea what you need to make it work for Code Blocks. `_setmode` and `_fileno` are Microsoft specific. CLion seems to be more MS compatible.

Comment: @zett42, I solve it! Code Blocks has `STDOUT_FILENO` macro, and `_O_U16TEXT` can be replaced by `0x20000` :)