# How to get a specific sub-folder path under root path?

Tags: c++11, visual-c++

I want to get the location of a specific folder under a root directory.
For example, I has a root directory as `C:\Dummy` and I have a sub directory inside this folder that is:

> C:\Dummy\10\20\MyFolder

Now I want to get the path of sub directory `MyFolder` under directory `C:\Dummy`.

I will write a function where I will pass two inputs:
1) "Root Folder" i.e. `C:\Dummy`
2) "Sub-Directory Name" i.e. `MyFolder`.

```
String fun(string RootFolderPath, string subDirName)
{

  //if any of the sub directories consists of `subDirName` then return the 
  //path
  return subDirPath;
}
```

Is there any way exists to achieve this?

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What do you expect to get? `10\20\MyFolder`?

Comment: @Kane, This is what I expect "C:\Dummy\10\20\MyFolder".

Comment: So you want something like `std::string findDirectory(const std::string &root, const std::string &directory)` which would find a corresponding directory on a filesystem and return its path? Could you please update your question with more details regarding what input data do you have and what what output do you expect?

Comment: @Kane, Something like what you mentioned. I updated my question in detail.

Comment: Thank you, now it is much clearer what the problem is. Please check acraig5075's answer below. If you want to use WinAPI, maybe you will find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639874/recursively-searching-for-files-in-the-computer.

Answer (score 0):

Using the experimental [filesystem](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs) standard library it can be done as follows:

```
#include <experimental\filesystem>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

string search_path(const string &root, const string &search)
{
    fs::path root_path(root);
    fs::path search_path(search);

    for (auto &p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(root_path))
        {
        if (fs::is_directory(p.status()))
            {
            if (p.path().filename() == search)
                return p.path().string();
            }
        }

    return "";
}
```

Otherwise, you have to use windows.api specific [file management functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232(v=vs.85).aspx) like FindFirstFile() and FindNextFile() to do the traversal. Or maybe the Boost [filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library.

Answer (score 0):

Create full directory path by concatenating *RootFolderPath* and *subDirName* (don't forget to insert "\" in between).  And use following 2 Windows APIs:

```
auto bDirExists = (::PathFileExists(path) && ::PathIsDirectory(path));
```